# Vue SSR serverPrefetch server redirect with this.$ssrContext.res.redirect

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router, vue-ssr

Is it possible to do a redirect from a component, in VUE SSR, without getting the error on the server console: `[ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`?

Code is as follows:

```
serverPrefetch() {
    // need the data from this.fetchPage service to decide on the redirect
    return this.fetchPage().then(function (response) {
        // do some checks here

        // THIS IS THE NODE EXPRESS REDIRECT
        this.$ssrContext.res.redirect('/');
        this.$ssrContext.res.end(); // with or without, same error
    }.bind(this));
},
beforeMount() {
    this.fetchPage();
}
```

NOTE: If I try to use `this.$router.replace('/')` (or any other methods), I get the error: `[Vue warn]: Error in callback for watcher $route: ReferenceError: document is not defined`.

In my project I did the redirect on the client side, but I was wondering if this can be done also from server.

Comment: Normally Redirects are done in the middlewares or pages and not the serverPrefetch method. After what condition are you trying to redirect?

Comment: @user3254198, I need to get some data from the one of the api calls (that fetchPage has multiple api calls) that tells me to redirect (ex, status 301 / 302), but only for that page. Right now the project is implemented after the https://ssr.vuejs.org documentation. In nodejs I don't have explicit routes, only app.get('*', renderApp)

Comment: Try doing the redirect in the nodejs server in the renderApp function. You shouldn't be making network requests inside components, only the page components should be making network requests otherwise it'll give you problems and make your app slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR:

> Reject the serverPrefetch with {url: '/redirect-route'}

Found the solution as follows: If you implement the vue-ssr project as the https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0 repo, in server/index.js you have a handleError function that has a redirect in it:

```
if (err.url) {
        res.redirect(err.url);
    }
```

And all you need to do in your component is:

```
serverPrefetch() {
    return this.fetchPage().then(res => {
        if(res === 'MY_REDIRECT_CONDITION') {
            // !!! THE ACTUAL REDIRECT TRIGGER !!!
            return Promise.reject({url: '/'});
        }

    });
},
```